# Need paint help

Tags: repair, paint, repainting

A painting fell and made a tiny scrape.  I thought I could fix it but I made it worse.  The paint I used matches but when you look on the side view it looks way to white. I sanded it down cause I panicked so now its super smooth.  I don't want to get in trouble by my landlord.

Comment: pictures would go a long way to enable us to help.

Comment: Is the scratch in the painting or in the wall, or a piece of furniture, or...? Please [edit] your post to provide some details & clarity. Oh, and a picture or two of the damage will help, too.

Comment: How long have you lived in the apartment? How old is the paint?  (Landlords *expect* to repaint every 7-10 years anyway).

Answer (score 1):

I bet the problem is just a slight mismatch in the sheen of the old and new paint.  Color and sheen can change on old paint as it ages.  As long as the color match is pretty good, paint the whole wall with your matching paint.  Once the whole wall is the same color and sheen, it'll be indistinguishable.

Comment: So true even the same paint applied a month later or different conditions of temp and humidity can look different. A spray can of texture can give the bumps back and repaint, don’t mask off when spraying texture fade out. Let dry and repaint the entire area.